# Table ranges with BigQuery's standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

How can you query a range of timestamped tables with the [new syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax)? Using `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` returns the error `Unhandled node type in from clause: TVF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of BigQuery supports an equivalent of table wildcards with Standard SQL. The documentation is available here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables.

Also please take a look at this post:

[Is there an equivalent of table wildcard functions in BigQuery with standard SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664185/is-there-an-equivalent-of-table-wildcard-functions-in-bigquery-with-standard-sql)