# Is there an equivalent of table wildcard functions in BigQuery with standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

In legacy `SQL`, users can use table wildcard functions like `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`, `TABLE_QUERY` and `TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT`.

Is there a similar feature with standard `SQL`?

Answer (score 14):

In legacy SQL, users can reference data from a subset of tables in a dataset using table wildcard functions. In standard SQL, users can achieve the same result using `UNION ALL`. However, this approach may not be convenient when users want to dynamically determine the set of tables using, for example, either a date range (supported using `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` and `TABLE_DATE_RANGE_STRICT` in legacy SQL) or other complex criteria (supported by `TABLE_QUERY` in legacy SQL). With Standard SQL, BigQuery offers an equivalent to this described below.

The following legacy SQL query that uses the `TABLE_QUERY` wildcard function can be rewritten using standard SQL.

**Legacy SQL query (using `TABLE_QUERY`):**

```
SELECT SUM(value1)
FROM TABLE_QUERY([myproject:mydataset],"table_id = 'mydailytable_20150105' OR
table_id = 'mydailytable_20150106' OR table_id = 'maydailytable_20150110'")
GROUP BY value2;
```

**Legacy SQL query (using `TABLE_DATE_RANGE`):**

```
SELECT SUM(value1)
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([myproject:mydataset], TIMESTAMP("2015-01-05"), TIMESTAMP("2015-01-10"))
```

**Standard SQL query:**

```
SELECT SUM(value1)
FROM `myproject.mydataset.mydailytable_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20150105'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20150106'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20150110'
GROUP BY value2;
```

In the above query, the wildcard table `myproject.mydataset.mydailytable_*` matches all tables in the dataset `myproject.mydataset` that have `table_id` starting with `mydailytable_`. For example, to match all tables in the dataset the user can use an empty prefix for the wildcard. So, `myproject.mydataset.*` matches all tables in the dataset.

Since `*` is a special character, wildcard table names must be quoted when using them in a query.

**The `_TABLE_SUFFIX` pseudo column:**

The `_TABLE_SUFFIX` pseudo column has type STRING and can be used just like any other column. It is a reserved column name, so it needs to be aliased when using it as part of the SELECT list.

Official documentation for this feature is available here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Comment: Can you add link to the official documentation please

Comment: wow, it actually works! what left to know wether it will actually be supported in release version

Comment: This is already supported in the latest version of BigQuery, we are just waiting on the official documentation for this to be available. I will post a link once we have it ready. Thanks!

Comment: wow again! so it is not just specific to sharded tables - it can be applied to any tables with common prefix and the '*' will be assigned to whatever suffix will happen to be. hope documentation will surface much more cool stuff!

Comment: This is indeed true, but please note that the schema used for the table for evaluating the query comes from the newest table (in terms of creation time). Any schema incompatibles among the constituting tables will cause an error.

Comment: understood and makes sense! we have some date sharded by let's say accounts so it can be very useful here. and i see more uses for this

Comment: I got "Error: Table myproject:mydataset.mytable_* is not queryable with legacy SQL." Can you please share a cod sample that run on publicly available dataset?

Comment: The feature is available only with Standard SQL (In the BigQuery UI, Click on Show Options and uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" option). Example: SELECT CONCAT("gsod", _TABLE_SUFFIX),
       AVG(temp)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*`
GROUP BY _TABLE_SUFFIX
ORDER BY 1;

Comment: Hi Pavan, the example from the public data works, but it doesn't work for one of our own datasets, the query validator says "Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."

Comment: Maybe something to do with the location of the dataset (we use EU)?

Comment: It's unclear what might be going on. If you want to share the BigQuery job id  , I can take a look. If you don't want to provide it here, please feel free to open an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/.

Comment: So how would I use this to select a date range using Standard SQL?

Comment: For example: If you have several dated tables mydataset.mytable_20160101, mydataset.mytable_20160102 ... mydataset.mytable_20160615

If you want to operate over data between May 21 2016 and June 14 2016, the query would be:
SELECT ... FROM `mydataset.mytable_2015*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '0521' AND '0614'  ?

If you want June 15th 2015 to June 14th 2016, the query would be:
SELECT ... FROM `mydataset.mytable_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20150615' AND '20160614'

Comment: Added documentation link.

Comment: Minor update -- the problem with EU datasets returning an error with such queries has been fixed as of a few weeks ago. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: How could I query suffixes from, say, 10 days ago until today in Standard SQL?

Comment: @Bugs - you should post separate question