# TABLE_DATE_RANGE for xxxx_yyyymm format tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having a problem trying to query for 15 months worth of data.
I know about bigquery's wildcard functions, but I can't seem to get them to work with my tables.

For example, if my tables are called:

> xxxx_201501,
>   xxxx_201502,
>   xxxx_201503,
>   ...
>   xxxx_201606

How can I select everything from `201501` until today (**current_timestamp**)?

It seems that it's necessary to have the tables per day, am I wrong?

I've also read that you can use `regex` but can't find the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Standard SQL, you can use a WHERE clause on a _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column as described here:

[Is there an equivalent of table wildcard functions in BigQuery with standard SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664185/is-there-an-equivalent-of-table-wildcard-functions-in-bigquery-with-standard-sql/)

In this particular case, it would be:

```
SELECT ... from `mydataset.xxx_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '201501';
```

Comment: If this works, it will prove quite useful for me.  Thanks.

Comment: You are the man! Thanks a bunch. It's a pity I can't get it to work with legacy SQL since I have to change my query, but this will suffice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

If you are using the standard SQL dialect, then I don't think the functionality is yet implemented.

If you are using the legacy SQL dialect, then you can use a function such as `TABLE_DATE_RANGE()`.  This and other table wildcard functions are well [documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference).

EDIT:

Oh, I see.  The simplest way would be to store the tables as YYYYMM01 so you can use the range query.

But, you can also use `table_query()`:

```
from table_query(t, 'right(table_id, 6) >= ''201501'' ')
```

Comment: I am indeed using the legacy SQL. I know about the function "TABLE_DATE_RANGE()" and I've read the documentation properly. But it seems that they are only useful for daily tables, such as xxxx_20160601, xxxx_20160602 and so forth. That's why I'm asking! Any workaround?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` or something similar for the second argument.

Comment: OK. I may not have explained myself well. It looks like TABLE_DATE_RANGE function only works with DAILY tables, such as table_nameYYYYmmdd, not table_nameYYYYmm (like mines are), therefore everytime I try anything with the table_date_range function this error happens: "FROM clause with table wildcards matches no table", because its not matching any of them.

Comment: As I can read in the documentation "Table names must have the following format: <prefix><day>, where <day> is in the format YYYYMMDD." I'm just asking for a workaround for this, such as a regex that finds numbers bigger than 201501.

Comment: Pavan's approach works. But standard SQL does not let me use json functions that legacy SQL does. I will try your approach, hopefully it works and I can also use json_extract for example. Thanks a lot to you guys. Will reply soon.