# format the timestamp output for TABLE_DATE_RANGE() BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a requirement to query different tables a once to save my time. Tables names like

> abc_yyyymmdd

can be easily query using the

```
table_date_range(abc_,timestamp('2016-01-01'),timestamp('2016-03-12'))
```

but I have different format table name

> abc_mm_dd_yyyy

is there a way to query in these tables using table_date_range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Legacy SQL you can use TABLE_QUERY for this

So it can be something like below

```
SELECT *  
FROM (
  TABLE_QUERY(YourDataset, 'LEFT(table_id, 4) = "abc_" AND LENGTH(table_id) = 14
  AND CONCAT(SUBSTR(table_id,11,4),'-',SUBSTR(table_id,5,2), -",SUBSTR(table_id,8,2)) 
    BETWEEN "2016-01-01" AND "2016-03-12"')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Standard SQL, you can use the _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column to work with any table name format.

[Is there an equivalent of table wildcard functions in BigQuery with standard SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664185/is-there-an-equivalent-of-table-wildcard-functions-in-bigquery-with-standard-sql)

In this case, it would be something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM `mydataset.abc_2016_*` WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '01-01' or _TABLE_SUFFIX = '03-12'
```